# Chat Application with Php Backend and C# front end

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

So I am thinking of creating an Xamarin Chatting Application for Android/iOS with C# as fornt End and using Php as web services. So I am little stuck. What should I use, Sockets, Web services via Php or something else. I want people to chat around the world.

Comment: why not mqtt or xmpp? or even webrtc signalling?

Comment: Well I am a newbie, and this is a first time creating chat application. I am thinking of using websockets as my php Api service will be hosted on a domain so I think I might use that.

Comment: If you just want to learn something then go for Web-services. Otherwise you can explore Google Firebase Realtime DB https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: Well I know of firebase but I don't think I can afford this hence I am thinking for going with stateless web-services, (GET,POST) but is it efficient??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I end up using RestFul Services to complete my Task